# Why am I getting a Oops, an error occurred! when I'm trying to do a fresh install on my shared host?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm tryin to install 9.5.9 LTS on a shared host. Version 8 runs properly but 9, I canot even start the Install Tool. When I open the first page (typo3/install.php) I get immediately a error page. I'm a Typo3 newbie, can you help?

```
Mon, 14 Oct 2019 13:20:22 +0000 [WARNING] request="" component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Error.ErrorHandler": Core: Error handler (FE): PHP Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(C:/Inetpub/vhosts/jvoquimica.pt/httpdocs/site6/typo3/sysext/*/) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:/Inetpub/vhosts/jvoquimica.pt\;C:\Windows\Temp\;C:/Inetpub/vhosts/jvoquimica.pt\site6\;) in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\jvoquimica.pt\httpdocs\site6\vendor\symfony\finder\Finder.php line 596 
Mon, 14 Oct 2019 13:20:22 +0000 [CRITICAL] request="" component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Error.ProductionExceptionHandler": Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1203699034: A cache with identifier "assets" does not exist. | TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Exception\NoSuchCacheException thrown in file C:\Inetpub\vhosts\jvoquimica.pt\httpdocs\site6\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Cache\CacheManager.php in line 137. Requested URL: https://www.jvoquimica.pt/site6/ - {"TYPO3_MODE":"FE","exception":"TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Exception\\NoSuchCacheException: A cache with identifier \"assets\" does not exist. in C:\\Inetpub\\vhosts\\jvoquimica.pt\\httpdocs\\site6\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Cache\\CacheManager.php:137\nStack trace:\n#0
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this to get a "readable" error message:
https://www.naderio.de/oops-an-error-occurred-komplette-fehlermeldung-anzeigen/

Maybe it would help if you can specify your system a bit - e.g. which hoster?